# express/node.js — req.getHeader is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning node.js/express and I'm trying to get the Date value from the header and send it to the front-end.

I can't seem to use `req.getHeader()` to do this. I'm also trying to `console.log(req)` and `console.log(req.headers)` but the output is different than the headers in postman.

This is what `console.log(req.headers)` gives me:

```
{
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': '6d5acbf2-b63d-46d4-b189-86e163281421',
  host: 'localhost:3001',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive'
}
```

Which is different from what postman headers are:

[image: postman]

Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

let persons = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Arto Hellas",
    number: "040-123456",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Ada Lovelace",
    number: "39-44-5323523",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Dan Abramov",
    number: "12-43-234345",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Mary Poppendieck",
    number: "39-23-6423122",
  },
];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/api/persons", (req, res) => {
  res.json(persons);
});

app.get("/api/persons/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = Number(req.params.id);
  const person = persons.find((person) => person.id === id);
  const unknown = persons.id == "unknown";

  if (person) {
    res.json(person);
  } else {
    res.status(404).end();
  }
});

app.get("/info", (req, res) => {
  let count = persons.length;
  let str = `Phonebook has info for ${count} people.`;

  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.headers);

  let timeDate = req.getHeader(Date); // <-- here is the problem
  console.log(timeDate);
  res.send(`<p>${str} \n ${timeDate}</p>`);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you're using Express, then it's better to use:

```
req.get("someHeader")
```

as this normalizes a number of things (like case sensitivity and interchangeable header names).

Then, you must pass it a String as in:

```
req.get("Date");
```

Note that incoming http requests from the browser do NOT contain a `Date` header.  So, there will only be such a header if you have some sort of custom client that is adding that header.

Your `req.getHeader()` is not working because such a method does not exist for an incoming http message object.  This is a bit confusing in the nodejs docs, but you are looking at the `http.ClientRequest` object.  That is not what you get as the `req` parameter for an incoming http request.  You get an `http.IncomingMessage` object which is documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage) and does not have a `req.getHeader()`.  It has `req.headers` which gives you the whole object of headers which you can then access the one you want.

Or, just use `req.get("Date")` that Express provides which gives you case insensitive access.  Keep in mind that incoming http requests from a browser do not have a `Date` header so for your server to use that header, it will have to be from a client that adds that header to its request.  Responses from your server back to the browser will have a `Date` header.

---

The object in the doc you were probably looking at that does have a `req.getHeader()` method is a [http.ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) object which is what you get back from `http.get()` and it refers to an outgoing http request from a client, not an incoming http request on your server.

Yes, this is a bit confusing since all the examples tend to use the same `req` variable name, yet different uses produce different objects for that variable.

Comment: I did try putting it in strings as well. Nothing. `req.getHeader("Date")` still gives me function doesn't exist error. `req.get("Date")` returns `undefined`. I'm using express. I must be doing some stupid mistake because even if I do `console.log(req.body);`, it hangs.

Comment: @Julian - Use `req.get()` instead, then.  Perhaps Express or something else is overriding `req.getHeader()`.  The documented Express method is `req.get()`.  I'll look further into why `req.getHeader()` isn't working.

Comment: @Julian - I figured out the issue.  Please see my edited answer above.

Comment: `req.get()` didn't work for me either. It returns `undefined`. In this case, to get the date, I just used `new date()`.  It might be a middleware issue, which I will have to figure out some other time...

Comment: @Julian - Look at `req.headers` and see if there even is a `Date` header.  As I said before, incoming requests from the browser do NOT contain a `Date` header.  It is not automatically there by default.

Comment: @Julian - One more thing.  The headers you show in Postman are the RESPONSE headers (what the server sends back to the client).  In Express, your code is looking at the REQUEST headers (what the client sends to the server).  Those are not the same thing at all.  By default, a browser request does not have a Date header on the request so Express will not see an incoming Date header.  By default Express does send back a Date header on the response.

Comment: @Julian - So, all of this boils down to two things:  First, you're looking for a Date header on the incoming request and one does not exist and second you're using the wrong method to get the Date header (even if it did exist).

Answer (score 0):

What Version of node are you using ? Try and upgrade to the LTS version. all should work

Answer (score 0):

use camelCase, change `postman-token` to `postmanToken`. because the custom header will auto-remove in express.